# Attribute Based Routing Not Working in MVC5 (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Recently our project is migrated from MVC4 to MVC5. I'm trying to implement attribute based routing but I'm getting below exception when I debug the following line routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

> Could not load file or assembly 'AspNetPerformance, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: So do you have a dll called `AspNetPerformance` that is missing?

Comment: Try install in NuGet `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`

Comment: @David I couldn't find this dll in the entire solution. Have we missed this while migrating the project? If yes then please help me to add this

Comment: I don't know what that library is, check if it's references in any of your projects.